# Copy data to offset cell in same worksheet in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

My aim is to take the value and copy it and name it with an extra character.

For example, in my B Column I have values named Example1 to Example4
[image]

I am trying to copy them a few cells down as seen in O Column. I can't just copy and offset down by four rows each time because my data has different number of rows between them.

My aim was to use Column C as the reference point to offset it and gather the information. This is probably not the best practice to have and again.

```vb
Sub Test()

    Dim addExample As String
    
    Set rngCC = Range("C1:C3000")
    
    addExample = "addEx"
    
    For Each cell In rngCC
    
        If cell = addExample Then
        
            ActiveCell.Select
            
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
            
            Selection.End(xlUp).Select
            
            Selection.Copy
            
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
            
            Cells.Find(What:="addEx", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
            
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
            
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            
            ActiveCell.Select
            
            ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & "b"
        
        End If
    
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you your required result:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim r as Long, LastRow as Long
    With ActiveSheet
    
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        
        For r = 1 To LastRow
            If .Cells(r, "C") = "AddEx" Then
                .Cells(r, "B").Value = .Cells(r, "B").End(xlUp).Value & "b"
                .Cells(r, "B").End(xlUp).Value = .Cells(r, "B").End(xlUp).Value & "a"
                .Cells(r, "C").ClearContents
            End If
        Next
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```